# Pickle can't store an object in django locmem cache during tests?

Tags: python, django, caching, pickle

Something that's puzzling me a bit...

```
>>> from django.core.cache import get_cache
>>>
>>> cache = get_cache('django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache')
>>>
>>> # Set the 'content' cache key to a string
>>> cache.set('content', 'a string')
>>> cache.get('content')
'a string'
>>>
>>> class TestObj(object):
...     pass
>>>
>>> a = TestObj()
>>> cache.set('content', a)
>>>
>>> # cache hasn't updated...
>>> cache.get('content')
'a string'
>>>
>>> cache.set('content', 1)
>>> # this is fine however..
>>> cache.get('content')
1
>>>
```

Ok, so the cache doesn't accept objects for some reason.

```
# in locmem.py, set() method
try:
    pickled = pickle.dumps(new_value, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
    self._cache[key] = pickled
except pickle.PickleError:
    pass
```

This will be why, it's obviously hitting the PickleError

```
>>> import pickle
>>> pickled = pickle.dumps(a, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1374, in dumps
    Pickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 224, in dump
    self.save(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 331, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 396, in save_reduce
    save(cls)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 748, in save_global
    (obj, module, name))
PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'TestObj'>: it's not found as __builtin__.TestObj
```

Sure thing, but why is this happening? It works just fine in the python console, but not the django shell?

```
# Works fine in python shell...
>>> import pickle  
>>> class TestObj(object):
...     pass
... 
>>> testobj = TestObj()   
>>> pickled = pickle.dumps(testobj, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
>>> pickled
'\x80\x02c__main__\nTestObj\nq\x00)\x81q\x01}q\x02b.'
>>>
```

This problem arose because I'm trying to store a Mock() object in the cache for a test. Not sure if I'm going about this the wrong way...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens because django LocMemCache uses cPickle instead of pickle by default. You can see it in LocMemCache class:

```
try:
    from django.utils.six.moves import cPickle as pickle
except ImportError:
    import pickle
```

If you will try to do in shell:

```
from django.utils.six.moves import cPickle as pickle
testobj = TestObj()
pickled = pickle.dumps(testobj, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

It will be the same error.

As possible solution I propose you to pack objects manually in your tests using pickle and after that do cache.set():

```
a = TestObj()
pickled = pickle.dumps(a, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
cache.set('content', pickled)
```

Comment: Ah that explains it. Thanks I missed that. I don't think I can pre-pickle the object as per your solution though, as it's the method that I'm testing that calls cache.set() as opposed to my tests. Thanks though.

Comment: Sorry, I just tried this in the python shell and I don't get the error when using `from django.utils.six.moves import cPickle`, but I DO get it in the django shell. So what is it about using the django shell that causes this error? I don't think it's inherently a cPickle problem

Comment: I don't pretty sure about it. But one of possible reasons of such behavior could be different python versions in your shells, because django.utils.six.moves exists for compatibility between python2 and python3 (https://pythonhosted.org/six/#module-six.moves). To check it you can insert "print pickle.__file__" in django/core/cache/backends/locmem.py

Comment: I'm not even using LocMemCache for these experiments I'm currently doing though, my testing is taking place entirely in the python shell or the django shell using my TestObj class and the direct `cPickle`, `pickle`, or `django.utils.six.moves.cPickle` classes. I'm using the same version of python in both examples (2.7.5+)

Comment: In that case "print cPickle.__file__" in your tests (when you do import cPickle and from django.utils.six.moves import cPickle). To be sure that it is the same module.

Comment: `django.utils.six.moves.cPickle` is a built in module and thus will not have a `__file__` attribute... ditto for the stanard cPickle

Comment: It's very interesting. I wonder to know if you will find the reason of such behavior.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that pickle serializes classes by reference, so could you not just use a better serializer that pickles the class by serializing the class definitions instead of by reference?  Then you'd pickle a mock object, which would then pickle the class source code, and then you'd be able to pass that to the django cache. I'm the author of `dill`, which is a better serializer… and also the author of `klepto`, which is a caching package… and this is exactly what I do to store any object in a SQL table, on disk, or in an in-memory cache.

Essentially (not trying this, but guessing it works based on experience with my own caching package), it should work like this:

```
>>> from django.core.cache import get_cache
>>> import dill
>>>
>>> cache = get_cache('django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache')
>>>
>>> # Set the 'content' cache key to a string
>>> cache.set('content', dill.dumps('a string'))
>>> dill.loads(cache.get('content'))
'a string'
>>>
>>> class TestObj(object):
...     pass
>>>
>>> a = TestObj()
>>> cache.set('content', dill.dumps(a))
>>>
>>> dill.loads(cache.get('content'))
<__main__.TestObj object at 0x10235e510>
>>>
>>> # this is pickling classes w/o using a reference
>>> dill.dumps(a)
'\x80\x02cdill.dill\n_create_type\nq\x00(cdill.dill\n_load_type\nq\x01U\x08TypeTypeq\x02\x85q\x03Rq\x04U\x07TestObjq\x05h\x01U\nObjectTypeq\x06\x85q\x07Rq\x08\x85q\t}q\n(U\r__slotnames__q\x0b]q\x0cU\n__module__q\rU\x08__main__q\x0eU\x07__doc__q\x0fNutq\x10Rq\x11)\x81q\x12}q\x13b.'
>>> # and here's using a reference, which is exactly how pickle does it
>>> dill.dumps(a, byref=True)
'\x80\x02c__main__\nTestObj\nq\x00)\x81q\x01}q\x02b.'
```

If you want to try it yourself, get `dill` (and `klepto`) here: https://github.com/uqfoundation

Answer (score 0):

WIth help from Martijn in [this follow-up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24245990/python-pickle-misbehaving-in-django-shell-as-opposed-to-python-shell/24247200#24247200) it turns out the short answer is:

"Yup".

You can't pickle Mock() objects as they do not provide the top-level object that they are mocking so pickle therefore has no idea where to import from. As the cache requires the object to be pickled to store it, it is not possible to store a Mock() instance in the LocMemCache. Will have to rethink how I go about testing this.

Answer (score 0):

## sample code

```
import pickle  # or from django.utils.six.moves import cPickle as pickle
lass TestObj(object):
     pass
testobj = TestObj()   
pickled = pickle.dumps(testobj, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
pickled
'\x80\x02c__main__\nTestObj\nq\x00)\x81q\x01}q\x02b.'
```

i can't understand a behavior, when i open a console session with "python manage.py shell" and execute: **_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle : attribute lookup builtins.TestObj failed**

but when open a single python console and execute the same code, works fine! Is there a reason?

I observed too, if i open a single console, and import **from django.utils.six.moves import cPickle as pickle** works fine too. The problem just occours when the code is executed in django context. :(