# python: pickle misbehaving in django shell as opposed to python shell?

Tags: python, django, pickle

As an additional question stemming from [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24240001/pickle-cant-store-an-object-in-django-locmem-cache-during-tests/24241848#24241848) it turns out that pickle behaves differently in django shell compared to python shell...

this script:

```
import pickle

class TestObj(object): pass
testobj = TestObj()
pickled = pickle.dumps(testobj, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

will work fine in python shell, but in django shell will raise a `PickleError` along the lines of `PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'TestObj'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.TestObj failed`

Is anyone able to explain the issue here? and if possible, link it back to my previous question?

Comment: Sounds like pickle cannot locate the `TestObj` created in the Django shell; it's environment is set up slightly differently from the interpreter. Specifically, `__name__` appears to be different.

Comment: interesting. does this behaviour extend to the actual django processes too then? If you look at my previous question, I was having difficulty storing a Mock() object in django's LocMemCache during my tests, and assumed it was caused by the same PickleError that occured in shell, but perhaps it isn't?

Comment: No, on pickling, the `pickle` module only stores instant data plus the location of where to import the class again. It will test if the class can be imported for this, and that test fails due the way the Django interactive prompt appears to be set up (`TestObj.__module__` points to `__builtin__`, apparently).

Comment: In a regular Django process, the setup is not 'special'. Test this with an object that is 'importable'. In the interactive prompt, store it on another module and re-point `__module__`; `import somemodule`, `somemodule.TestObj = TestObj`, `TestObj.__module__ = 'somemodule'` will pretend to Python that `from somemodule import TestObj` is the canonical way to re-import the class.

Comment: I see, so it looks like I'm getting a completely different `PicklingError` using Mock- which is cryptic in and of itself: `PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'mock.Mock'>: it's not the same object as mock.Mock`

Comment: Ah, yes: https://code.google.com/p/mock/issues/detail?id=139

Comment: Damn :) So it looks like my attempt to store Mock() in the cache is doomed to failure. Thanks anyway, if you want to compile that into an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pickle` will make sure it can re-import a class, as only the data on the instance itself is pickled, plus the import location of the class. As such, `pickle` looks for the `__module__` attribute on the class to determine where it came from.

It appears the Django interactive environment does not *set* this `__module__` attribute; as a result `TestObj.__module__` is inherited from the `object` base class instead, and that's `__builtin__`. Perhaps no `__name__` global is set. As a result, the `pickle` module ends up looking in the wrong place for your class. There is no `__builtin__.TestObj` after all.

From the comments, I gather that you are trying to store mocked objects in the Django cache. That won't work, as [mock objects are not pickleable](https://code.google.com/p/mock/issues/detail?id=139). That makes sense, as on *unpickling* (which could be in an entirely new Python process), how would `pickle` know what original class was being mocked?

Answer (score 1):

Could you not just use a serializer that doesn't pickle classes by reference… and then pre-serialize what you pass into the django cache?  This would store not only the instance, but also the class definition itself -- which should allow you to reconstruct the instance anywhere.

See my answer on your original question:
[Pickle can't store an object in django locmem cache during tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24240001/pickle-cant-store-an-object-in-django-locmem-cache-during-tests/26164781#26164781)

I don't know anything about django Mock objects, or if there's something especially unpicklable about them…  But as long as they are built from python code (as opposed to built in C, and have a thin python wrapper layer), then the above should likely work.