# How do I use socket objects inside Celery tasks using Django?

Tags: django, serialization, redis, socket.io, celery

I am stuck with an issue regarding serializing socket objects for a long time and need help. Before I state my problem, here is the technology stack of the application I am building.

- Django-1.8.7
- Redis
- Celery
- MySQL
- gevent-socketio
- greenlet

#### Here is the background of the problem :

I want to send notifications asynchronously in my application without making the request wait for the notifications to be sent to the subscribers. I am using Celery to run the tasks for sending notifications via sockets which are created when a user logs in into the application. The problem is Celery doesnt recognize the sockets created inside the django application.

#### My attempts :

I tried multiple ways to serialize the sockets object and pass it to Celery task but I keep getting this error.
"Socket Object cannot be serialized"

I also tried storing the sockets in cache so that I can retrieve from the cache during the Celery task. But then I get this error while inserting into cache - "cannot serialize 'Hub' object" or ""cannot serialize 'Greenlet' object"
Also took help of the below answer, but no luck.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26164781/6876786

Can someone help me fix this problem?
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Did you solve this? because I'm having the same issue

Comment: @cydan - No buddy! Could find any resolve for this?